# Decode a json file properly, when get it as an input via message request

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, web-services, pytorch

I would like to read a request, sent via curl, as given below:

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/eval/res -v path/request.json. With the json having the following format:

```json
{
    "imgX": [{
        "key": "x",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/imgs/x.png"
    }],
    
    "imgY": [{
        "key": "y",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/imgs/y.png"
    }]
}
```

After service initialization, my code is:

```
 def preprocess(self, data):
    _json = {}
    for row in data:
        json_obj = row.get("data") or row.get("body")
        self.parameter_dict = dict(json_obj)
    image_url = ""
    json_obj = dict(json_obj)
    for img_inputs, msk_inputs in zip(json_obj['imgX'], json_obj['imgY']):
        key = img_inputs['key']
```

However, that gives:

```
KeyError: 'img'
```

I debug and find that when reading json file, each row is a bytearray:

```
{'body': bytearray(b'')}.
```

How can I decode to get the .json format back?

Comment: Is the issue `"imageX"` vs `"imgX"`?

Comment: Nope, corrected

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with json responses from APIs, you can use the `json` [lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). In particular `json.loads()` returns a dictionary so you don't have to convert things manually.

For example:

```
import json

with open('<path_to_file>/request.json','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    _json = json.loads(data)
    print(_json)
```

Would output:

```
{'imgX': [{'key': 'x', 'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/imgs/x.png'}],
 'imgY': [{'key': 'y', 'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/imgs/y.png'}]}
```

On the other hand, when using `zip()` **if** you are getting two lists `img_inputs` and `msk_inputs`, each with more than one json object/dictionary inside, in order to make `img_inputs['key']` work, you would need to loop over the values of those lists to get to the keys.

```
    #...   
    for img_inputs, msk_inputs in zip(json_obj['imgX'], json_obj['imgY']):
        key = img_inputs[0]['key']
    #...
```

In this case (I revised my code), `zip()` will return the first element in the list for `img_inputs` and `msk_inputs` so that step is not necessary and your for loop is fine.

Make sure you are getting a valid json response from the API.

Comment: i followed the solution with json.loads() for data, but got this: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: Please update your answer including the code for the data request. Also, according to [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/), the JSON you provided as example is not valid.

Comment: It is updated, the request is given via curl command at the beginning. The request.json is the aforementioned file. I can confirm that that service is initialized properly. However, I am not true whether the request is absolutely true, and if the error comes from that side. any help is welcomed.